Spring SAML: Single Logout fails due to blocked JSESSIONID cookie
Our application implements SAML Single Sign-On using spring-security 4.2.1 and spring-security-saml2-core 1.10.0. SLO does not work correctly. When logging out in a different application, the SLO request sent to us does not terminate the local session.
This seems to happen when the JSESSIONID cookie, which is stored by the IdP and included in the SAML logout request, is blocked by the browser. As a result, Spring cannot find the security context for the given session and so cannot terminate the session and returns with the error message "No user is logged in".
Before the logout request is processed, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter creates a new context because the session ID is missing.
HttpRequestResponseHolder holder = new HttpRequestResponseHolder(request,
        response);
SecurityContext contextBeforeChainExecution = repo.loadContext(holder);

try {
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(contextBeforeChainExecution);

    chain.doFilter(holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());

}

Next, SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout() tries to fetch the security context authentication object, which is null.
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
SAMLCredential credential = null;
if (auth != null) {
    credential = (SAMLCredential) auth.getCredentials();
}

Because the credential is null, SingleLogoutProfileImpl.processLogoutRequest() throws an exception.
// Check whether any user is logged in
if (credential == null) {
    throw new SAMLStatusException(StatusCode.UNKNOWN_PRINCIPAL_URI, "No user is logged in");
}

One of the first fixes I tried is setting the cookie's SameSite attribute. That was not set before, so browsers defaulted to SameSite=Lax and blocked the cookie on that basis. Setting SameSite=None fixes the problem but only if the browser is set to allow third-party cookies.
The next thing I tried is the Partitioned cookie attribute. However, browsers also block that cookie when the logout request is sent, on the basis that the cookie is partitioned to the IdP's domain instead of the application's domain. Plus, as of today not all browsers support partitioned cookies yet.
Perhaps it is possible that Spring can be configured/implemented to find the correct session for single logout processing based on the SAML message included in the logout request. Currently our application uses the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository implementation to find security contexts.

Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm researching this same issue right now.

Yes, thanks for asking! I haven't got around to posting the solution until now.

I have come up with my own solution to this. Unfortunately I am not allowed to share the code, so on the side of caution I will not do it. I will try my best to explain the solution without it.
I wrote a class that extends SecurityContextRepository to store security context objects in a map, where the key is the SessionIndex attribute from a SAML message. The class delegates all the other normal security context processing to HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository that we've used before.
In the method loadContext, I check if the request contains a LogoutRequest SAML message. If not, I call the delegate repository's loadContext. Otherwise, the parsed SAML message can be cast to a LogoutRequest object and the session index can be extracted and I can check if the security context map returns a security context with that session index.
Note that even when I return a security context found in the map, I still need to call the delegate's loadContext method because it also does request/response wrapping and if that's not done, it will cause exceptions.
In the saveContext method, I get the SAMLCredential from the Authentication object, which I get from the context passed to the method. The session index can be pulled from the SAMLCredential object, and the context can be put in the map. At the end of the method, I always call the delegate's saveContext method.
In this solution I opted to manually parse the SAML message when loadContext is called. I'm not sure if would be possible or practical to somehow pass the existing SAML processor bean and use that instead. This method of SAML parsing worked for me: http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-read-saml-20-response-with.html
Also note if you're manually parsing SAML messages: if HTTP-Redirect binding is used (i.e. if the logout request is a GET request), the SAML payload needs to be inflated. I used the Java Inflater object for this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html
Feel free to ask if you have any questions about this!

Thanks for the response! The more I was digging in, the more it looked like something like this would be the solution. The Service Provider that we are trying to "log out" doesn't belong to us though it is open source. I may look at providing a patch some time in the future.
